# How to make sure download prompt is triggered using express sendFile?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the code below in my express server

```
app.get('/download', async (req, res)=> {
  res.sendFile( `/dl/myfile.mp4`, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'mp4'},root: __dirname})
});
```

The sent file does not cause a download prompt in any of my tested browsers ( Chrome, Opera ) instead it shows me a player and starts playing the file while I need to it cause a download prompt.

How can I avoid the player and trigger a download prompt using Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoule use `res.download(filePathToServer)`

Transfers the file at path as an “attachment”. Typically, browsers will prompt the user for download if you use it.

You can read more about it here [res.download - express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using your answer like this res.download(`${__dirname}/dl/${req.query.fn}` , req.query.fn)